# How "infectious" is Unreal Engine 4 license? What is the scope of "product" definition?

Tags: software, licensing

According to Epic's [EULA for Publishers](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/eula/publishing), they want 5% of any gross revenue you might make out of using software built with their engine, including in-app purchases and advertising, before tax deduction.

However, if the actual game (built with Unreal Engine) is free-to-play, does not contain anything related to in-app purchases, but all game-altering purchases are instead done on game's website, so they are not technically "in-app" anymore.

Would be any revenue obtained this way still subject to 5% fee from Epic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems relatively clear that you owe them 5%...

> 5. Royalty
>
> You agree to pay Epic a royalty equal to 5% of all worldwide gross revenue actually attributable to each Product, regardless of whether that revenue is received by you or any other person or legal entity, as follows:
>
> a. Gross revenue resulting from any and all sales of a Product to end users through any and all media, including but not limited to digital and retail;
>   b. Gross revenue resulting from any and all in-app purchases, downloadable content, microtransactions, subscriptions, sale, transfer, or exchange of content created by end users for use with a Product, or redemption of virtual currency, either within a Product **or made externally but which directly affect the operation of the Product**;

The first line of the agreement seems egregious though, lets say you make a moddable game that you release for free. Somebody makes a mod and charges $100 for the mod and they get the revenue. It seems like this is saying that you, the developer, owe $5 for each sale of that mod. I don't see that as enforceable.